できる/potential form practise
I am learning the potential form and ことができる from my textbook. I made the following sentence up.
コンピューターが間違いができます！
コンピューターが間違えます！
And it was marked as wrong and labelled with
"We use potential form and "できる" for only positive effects. It is different from the English "can"." Say コンピューターも間違うことがあります！ instead.
I kind of get why to use も here, because im trying to say "Computers can also be wrong!" so that makes sense, but why cant we use potential form here?
Can someone please explain why my sentence is wrong?
Can I also say
ワイン売り場で買えるのでインターネットで注文しなかったです - Because I can buy it from the wine stand, I didnt order it online.
うちで食べられるので（or から)、レストランへ行きませんでした. (B/c I can eat at home, I didnt go to a restaurant)

Is there something about the explanation you were given that you are having difficulty with?

@leebo Yes, the explanation makes no sense to me hence the question. What does positive effects even mean in this context.

The potential form expresses that one has an ability to do something.  Is making a mistake really an ability?  If you still think yes, then consider an ability as a skill of sorts.  Is making mistakes a skill or the lack of skill.  Is it, for example, something you would list on a resume.  If not, then it's not a positive.

@A.Ellett. I am not 100% sure if I understand but am kind of following you. So does 魚が食べられない not make sense? Since its a lack of an ability to in this case eat fish...?

Being able to eat fish is an ability. So, I would say yes.  Just as if you were being interviewed for a job as a sushi chef and you were asked, "are you able to eat fish", you could answer, "no, I can't".  So yes, 魚が食べられない makes sense.  You're saying you lack that skill.

Thanks for your comment. @A.Ellett, do you have an example of where the potential form is incorrect or ungrammatical/inappropriate?

I'm not sure how to answer your question.  Your teacher has pointed out an instance in which the potential doesn't sound natural in Japanese.  In this context, I'm not sure what to make of the words "incorrect", "ungrammatical", or "inappropriate".  "Inappropriate" sounds like you're breaking a social taboo; I can't imagine how this would happen merely by using a potential form.  I can say "I can have to sleep".  Is that incorrect or ungrammatical?  Either way, it doesn't make much sense in English.  But, you can actually say "I have to be able to sleep" and have it make reasonable sense.

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/100328/5010

@naruto thats very helpful. So for example in the sentence "Humans can live on mars",  you wouldnt want to use potential form but use koto ga aru, because its a assertion, not an ability of someone/something right?

That depends on whether you want to say "Sometimes, humans live on Mars" or "Human beings can survive on Mars (with good shelters and spacesuits, if they want to)". If you mean the latter, you can use できる because it's about the ability of humans.

@naruto, that makes sense, but is confusing lol. Hopefully i can remember that

This answer is only responding on how to interpret the feedback you received from your teacher.  As a non-native speaker, my intuition on the nuance of these matters is not something I'm always willing to trust.
With that caveat out of the way, here are my thoughts on the matter.
As your teacher mentioned, English "can" is much more flexible than the Japanese potential.  Take for example the stereotypical admonishment of an English speaking student who asks, "Can I go to the bathroom?"  The teacher might response, "I'm sure you're able to go."  But the fact of the matter is that in informal situations, no one loses sleep over whether they say "may" or "can".
In English we also use "can" to indicate the possibility that something may happen.  So, if we say, "Machines can make mistakes", we understand this to be a claim of what's in the realm of the possible.  It's not talking about the skill of the machine (unless we're talking about AI perhaps).
And so, here we tread into an area of Japanese where this notion of "possibility" is questionably present in the use of the potential.
I feel I've seen the potential used in this manner (to describe a possibility) before in Japanese.  But, it seems to be very rare. When I have seen it, it stands out.  On this point, I'd prefer to defer to the native Japanese on their assessment of how natural the potential may sound in such usages.
So, let's just consider what your instructor told you:  the potential is only used when describing a positive effect.
This is where I think it's useful to consider that the potential in Japanese expresses a skill (or a lack of a skill when used in the negative).  There is no skill that anyone would call "making a mistake".  This is why in my comments to your original post I brought up the matter of what you would put on your resume.  You would never advertise "I am really awesome at occasionally making mistakes."
Eating fish doesn't sound like something you would advertise on a resume.  But, some people may have allergies perhaps and so they are not able to (safely) eat fish.  So, both of the following sentences make sense:

魚が食べられる
魚が食べられない (but there are other things you can eat)

Similarly, you can say

ピアノが弾ける
ピアノが弾けない (but you are musically talented in other ways)

In the first case, you're expressing that you are able to play piano.  In the second, you're expressing that you're not able to play piano; that is, you lack that particular skill.
As you noted, the second isn't exactly a positive effect.  However, if you think of the potential as expressing a skill, given that you may or may not lack that skill is something you should be able to express.
Now it seems to me there is yet another dimension in all of this.  When we say,

ピアノが弾ける

We're not saying that "the piano is able to play."
This is another area where care must be taken.  Who or what is the agent who possesses the ability?  Again, in English we can be flexible around these things.  But, in Japanese, I always have the sense that using something like the potential with an inanimate or nonsentient agents can come across a bit odd.  It's not that you cannot say these things.  I feel like I hear this usage of the potential occasionally in the news.  But the flexibility of the English can here is missing.
